# Adding a Java component to a Scala swing panel

Tags: swing, scala, java-3d

Well, I am trying to get Java3D working in Scala. I came to notice that the `Canvas3D` is a `Component` derived class, whereas the `scala.swing` classed only allow for, well, swing components, either `ScalaComponent` or `JComponent`. Here would be my code:

```
object HelloUniverse extends SimpleSwingApplication {
 def top = new MainFrame {
  title = "Java3D with Scala"

  contents = new BorderPanel {
   val config = SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration()
   val canvas = new Canvas3D(config)

   peer.add(canvas, "Center")
  }
 }
}
```

So yeah, with the `.peer` method I get the underlying `JPanel`. But how would I add a heavyweight component in there?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try using JCanvas3D**. It is based on JPanel.
More info at http://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.5.0/com/sun/j3d/exp/swing/JCanvas3D.html

Answer (score 2):

The **ScalaCanvas3D API** provides Scala Swing components for heavyweight and lightweigth Java 3D rendering. See '**Java 3D meets Scala**' for more details, sample programs, and downloads : http://www.interactivemesh.org/testspace/j3dmeetsscala.html